# String replace problem with inferior symbol

Tags: python, regex

I would like to replace the string "<75%" by "NONE".
I have write this function but it doesnt match :(

```
replacements = {'toot': 'titi-',
                '<75%': 'NONE'}

def replace(match):

    return replacements[match.group(0)]

def clean75Case(text_page):
    return re.sub('|'.join(r'\b%s\b' % re.escape(s) for s in replacements),
           replace, text_page)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(clean75Case("toot iiii <75%"))
```

Comment: `\b` matches the boundary between a word character and a non-word character.  `<` is a non-word character, as is the space before it in your string, so `\b` does't match there.

Comment: cleanAttend75Case is not defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the issue is that `\b` only matches the boundary between a word and non-word character. From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html):

> \b
>
> Matches the empty string, but only at the beginning or end of a word.
>   A word is defined as a sequence of word characters. Note that
>   formally, \b is defined as the boundary between a \w and a \W
>   character (or vice versa), or between \w and the beginning/end of the
>   string

In the string you gave, the space character () and the less than character (`<`) are both non-word characters. So `\b` does not match the empty space between them.

For an alternate way to solve this problem, consider using `split()` to split the string into words and comparing each word against the replacement patterns like so:

```
replacements = {'toot': 'titi-',
                '<75%': 'NONE'}

def clean75Case(text_page):
    words = text_page.split()
    return ' '.join(replacements.get(w, w) for w in words)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(clean75Case("toot iiii <75%"))
```